# Weird floating point exception c++ (pointer assignment)

Tags: c++, stl, floating-point, unordered-map

I want to create a tree-like structure, but based on a `unordered_map` of topics. On short, I want to create a topic tree and I thought of this approach:

```
typedef struct topic_tree {
    int id;
    unordered_map<string, struct topic_tree *> children;
} topic_tree;
```

Which sounds like a pretty good idea, because, for every "topic" I would have an ID for it (or whatever I need) and from every node then there will be a map from the next string to the next topic_tree and so on.

I tried to create this tree: `first/second/third`. This means that first it's the parent of second, and second is the parent of third.. There might be other things like `first/forth/fifty`
this means first has 2 children now, second and forth.. that's the explanation. Now let's get to the problem:

For example I'm declaring this:

```
topic_tree *root = (topic_tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct topic_tree));
root->id = -1;
topic_tree *x = (topic_tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct topic_tree));
x->id = 5;
root->children["first"]=x;
```

but this: `root->children["first"] = x;` gives me a `Floating point exception` and I have no idea why..

Comment: `topic_tree *root = (topic_tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct topic_tree));` -- Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  This is totally wrong. C++ is not C.

Comment: Then what should I use? To create such a thing I described. Sorry, I am new to C++.

Comment: Again C++ is not C.  You are creating C++ objects and they need to have their constructors called.  The `malloc` is a C function that knows nothing about creating objects or calling their constructor.  In C++, you use `new` to create such objects, not `malloc`.  If you find yourself reaching for `C` idioms in a C++ program, think again and reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `new` and `delete` and read it. I'm curious: how exactly have you learned about `std::unordered_map`s, and other advanced C++ library containers, without being aware of `new` and `delete`? Which C++ textbook dumped you straight into containers, without teaching fundamentals of dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Ideally, avoid the manually allocated memory completely if you can. Consider using `unordered_map<std::string, topic_tree>` instead. Also, your use of `typedef` for the struct is a C-ism that isn't necessary in C++.

Comment: So I can use `new` on the `struct topic_tree` even if It's not a pointer?

Comment: Well, first of all, you should not even use it. Very few things in modern C++ require explicit `new` and `delete`s. Most C++ code uses containers, which manage these things for them, or, at the most, higher-level constructs like `std::shared_ptr`. In any case, stackoverflow.com is not really a replacement for a C++ textbook, you should be able to find all the answers to your questions, of this kind, in your book. And you cannot effectively learn C++ from Google searches, which is the most common reason I see for malloc being used in C++ code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why  can't you just tell me or give me a link to read? I don't have any kind of textbook and neither did any kind of c++ coursework. I'm trying to learn, so why don't just tell me how it *should* be done?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand that what I want to achieve is very simple, but for a beginner into the C++ world, is not such a mundane task.

Comment: No.  The `new` returns a pointer to a new object.  I get the impression you're a C programmer who is under the impression that C++ is "close enough".  That is not true.  C++ has type categories that C does not have, namely non-POD types.  You can't throw around `malloc`, `memcpy`, or any of those lower-level C functions on them.

Comment: You cannot expect to learn C++ without a textbook, sorry. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. I've been working with C++ for >20 years, and I'm still learning. As in "today". That's just the facts. You are just confusing yourself if you attempt to stitch together some C++ knowledge from random Google searches and Youtube videos. I cannot give you a link because no such link exists. There is no link that will impact non-trivial amount of C++ knowledge on you, this can only come from a textbook, and formal, rigorous, studies.

Comment: @C.Cristi -- Here is a laymans explanation -- when you used `malloc`, all you did was request a number of bytes.  That's all.  You didn't actually create an object.  It's as if you asked for a brand new car (analogous to calling `new`), and instead of car that you can drive, you get all the parts dumped on the floor -- steering wheel, engine, nuts and bolts, etc.  The latter is what `malloc` gave you. You now attempt to "drive" all of those parts on the floor.  So you look weird sitting down on nuts and bolts hoping that the car starts.  Just like the weird "floating point error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because after you've allocated your `topic_tree` struct you're not initialising it.
So the `std::unordered_map` is working on uninitialised memory which dosn't work.

### Best solution using `new`/`delete`

In general within a C++ application you should avoid using `malloc`/`free`. Instead use the `new` and `delete` operator which will automatically call the object constructor on construction,
and the destructor on desctruction.
When allocating your nodes like this: `new topic_tree{}` you should be fine.

### If you're *required* to use `malloc`/`free`

If you want to stick with malloc, you've to explicitly call the constructor.
This could be done like this:

```
new (root) topic_tree{};
```

But be aware in order to `free` the object you need to call the destructor!

```
root->~topic_tree();
```

**Attention**: If you see this in your code its usually a code smell!
There are only very few applications for it!

### Modern solution (Memory management with smart pointers)

In modern C++ projects you mostly not even see any `new` or `delete` statements at all.
Instead for object allocation you use smart pointers like
`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (`std::auto_ptr` as well but its a bit different).
These containers will manage the objects lifetime automatically so you're not having to worry about that at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, how could I create such a structure I want using Classes?

Comment: The new operator works with struct and classes. In order to create a class just exchange the struct keyword into a class keyword. Be aware that by default the class member visibility is private, instead the  default struct member visibility is public.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that for writing idiomatic C++ normally you dont need any of this ;) rather smart pointers and no manual memory handling

Comment: @idclev463035818 Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @C.Cristi I refer to "If you want to stick with malloc". It is rare that you need to resort to `malloc`. Nothing in the answer is wrong, but there is almost no reason to use `malloc` in C++ and little reason to use `new` and deal with raw owning pointers when you can use smart pointers instead